# Laravel 4 how get routes by group name

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

In Laravel, I know I can get all routes using `Route::getRoutes() but I can't find if it is possible to get a list of all routes contained in a specified group.

For example, i have this route file:

```
Route::group(array('group_name' => 'pages'), function() {
    Route::any('/authentication', array('as' => 'authentication', 'uses' => 'LogController@authForm' ));
    Route::group(array('before' => 'auth_administration'), function() {
        Route::any('/tags_category/index', array('as' => 'index-tags-categories', 'uses' => 'TagsCategoryController@index'));
        Route::any('/tags_category/update', array('as' => 'update-tags-category', 'uses' => 'TagsCategoryController@update'));
    });
});

Route::group(array('before' => 'auth_administration'), function() {
    Route::any('/tags_category/store', array('as' => 'store-tags-category', 'uses' => 'TagsCategoryController@store')); 
    Route::any('/tags_category/update/{id}', array('as' => 'update-form-tags-category', 'uses' => 'TagsCategoryController@updateForm')); 
    Route::any('/tags_category/delete/{id}', array('as' => 'delete-tags-category', 'uses' => 'TagsCategoryController@delete'));
}); // operazioni protette
```

and in my controller i want obtain only routes contained in the first group (the one with the variable 'group_name').

Is it possible? If yes how I can do it? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The attributes passed to the group in the first parameter are stored on the route in the `action` array. This array can be accessed via the `getAction()` method on the route. So, once you get access to the route objects, you can filter based on this information.

```
$name = 'pages';
$routeCollection = Route::getRoutes(); // RouteCollection object
$routes = $routeCollection->getRoutes(); // array of route objects
$grouped_routes = array_filter($routes, function($route) use ($name) {
    $action = $route->getAction();
    if (isset($action['group_name'])) {
        // for the first level groups, $action['group_name'] will be a string
        // for nested groups, $action['group_name'] will be an array
        if (is_array($action['group_name'])) {
            return in_array($name, $action['group_name']);
        } else {
            return $action['group_name'] == $name;
        }
    }
    return false;
});

// array containing the route objects in the 'pages' group
dd($grouped_routes);
```

Answer (score -1):

User artisan to list all routes for the application

```
php artisan routes --name=admin
```

in Laravel 5

```
php artisan route:list --name=admin
```