# How to get routes list by specific groups in laravel 5?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Hello I am trying to do it like this but it's getting all the routes, I only want the routes from a specific group(s).

This is my code:

```
<?php 
$routes = Routes::getRoutes();
@foreach($routes as $route)
    {{ $route->getPath() }}
@endforeach`
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please give an example

Comment: for example : i have a permissions named column in my table in which i will store some specific routes which are related to a specific route group.

Answer (score 4):

**Let's create some routes without any groups**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/load', 'defaultController@load');
```

**Now we'll create some routes with groups**

```
Route::group(['as' => 'admin'], function () {
    Route::get('users', function ()    {
        return "users route";
    });

    Route::get('ravi', function ()    {
        return "ravi route";
    });
```

**Now we are going to create a route in this group which will look for the admin group and print all routes that exist in this group.**

```
Route::get('kumar', function ()    {
    $name = 'admin';
    $routeCollection = Route::getRoutes(); // RouteCollection object
    $routes = $routeCollection->getRoutes(); // array of route objects
```

**Now in our route object, we will look for our named route by filtering the array.**

```
 $grouped_routes = array_filter($routes, function($route) use ($name) {
            $action = $route->getAction(); // getting route action
            if (isset($action['as'])) {

                // for the first level groups, $action['as'] 
                // will be a string
                // for nested groups, $action['as'] will be an array

                if (is_array($action['as'])) {
                    return in_array($name, $action['as']);
                } else {
                    return $action['as'] == $name;
                }
            }
            return false;
        });


  // Here we will print the array containing the route objects in the 'admin' group
        dd($grouped_routes);
    });

});
```

**Now you can copy and paste this in your route folder and you will be able to see the output by hitting your_project_public_folder_url/kumar**

I took help from this answer [Answer of patricus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29943111/3317153)