# Where should I define my logic that will be used in a blade template?

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-blade, laravel-8

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68740120/how-to-get-all-routes-within-a-route-group) I got a nice answer with some code. I now wonder what is the intended laravel way of implementing this.

The code is:

```
function getRoutesByGroup(array $group = [])
{
    $list = \Route::getRoutes()->getRoutes();
    if (empty($group)) {
        return $list;
    }
    $routes = [];
    foreach ($list as $route) {
        $action = $route->getAction();
        foreach ($group as $key => $value) {
            if (empty($action[$key])) {
                continue;
            }
            $actionValues = Arr::wrap($action[$key]);
            $values = Arr::wrap($value);
            foreach ($values as $single) {
                foreach ($actionValues as $actionValue) {
                    if (Str::is($single, $actionValue)) {
                        $routes[] = $route;
                    } elseif($actionValue == $single) {
                        $routes[] = $route;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $routes;
}

Route::group(['as' => 'main'], function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('pages.start');
    })->name('Home');
    
    Route::get('/foobar', function () {
        return view('pages.foobar');
    })->name('Home');
    
    Route::get('/business', function () {
        return view('pages.business');
    })->name('Business');
});

getRoutesByGroup(['as' => 'main']); // where to load this?
```

I want to use this in two blade templates to render a menu. My first thought was to put this in a Trait and use that Trait within the `AppServiceProvider.php`, but this seems to only have 5 internal ignite routes available so I guess its too early in the bootstrapping process.

What is the correct way in this scenario? Do I make a Facade, another Service Container, do I load this via inject in a template, do I make a global var?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making a new service provider and used [view composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32942379/global-variable-in-laravel-controller/32942799).

Still, if there is a better and more MVCish way I'm glad for any input.